# Datatables with multiple tabs in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have two tabs and each tab contains a datatable.
I am trying to set column filters on both tables. My code for this is:

```
$(function() {
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "date-euro-pre": function (a) {
            if ($.trim(a) != '') {
                var frDatea = $.trim(a).split(' ');
                var frTimea = frDatea[1].split(':');
                var frDatea2 = frDatea[0].split('/');
                var x = (frDatea2[2] + frDatea2[1] + frDatea2[0] + frTimea[0] + frTimea[1] + frTimea[2]) * 1;
            } else {
                var x = 10000000000000; // = l'an 1000 ...
            }

            return x;
        },

        "date-euro-asc": function (a, b) {
            return a - b;
        },

        "date-euro-desc": function (a, b) {
            return b - a;
        }
    });
});

$(function() {
   $("#completed").dataTable({
        "bSort": false,
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            { "sType": "date-euro" },
            null,
            null,
            null,null,
            null
        ],
        "aaSorting": [[2, 'desc']]


    }).columnFilter({
        aoColumns: [
            null,
            {type: "select", values: ['SENT PAYMENT', 'RECEIVED PAYMENT', 'SENT REQUEST', 'RECEIVED REQUEST', 'RECHARGE', 'BILLPAY', 'PAYMENT MISSED']},
            null,
            {type:"select", values: ['WALLET','ACCOUNT']},

            {type:"select", values:['COMPLETED','ERRORED']},
            null,
            null,
            null
        ]

    });


 var b=   $("#pending").dataTable({
        "bSort": false,
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            {"sType": "date-euro"},
            null,
            null,
            null, null,
            null
        ],
        "aaSorting": [[2, 'desc']]

    }).columnFilter({
        aoColumns: [
            null,
            {
                type: "select",
                values: ['SENT PAYMENT', 'RECEIVED PAYMENT', 'SENT REQUEST', 'RECEIVED REQUEST', 'RECHARGE', 'BILLPAY', 'PAYMENT MISSED']
            },
            null,
            {type: "select", values: ['WALLET', 'ACCOUNT']},
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
        ]


    })
```

//

```
});
```

now the issue is that this only sets filter to the last table i.e table with id "pending". Can anyone help me to get this working?

Comment: Where you have declared variable a?

Comment: Which tab is active when the page first loads?

Comment: there is an example of datatables within bootsrap and the default filtering options if that helps at all https://datatables.net/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html

Comment: @ Chris The tab is activated dynamically but usually it is tab with id "pending"